# Azure Pipeline creates second source code folder (Build.SourcesDirectory), when trying to do multiple checkouts

Tags: git, azure, yaml, pipeline, checkout

I am trying to run an Azure pipeline, where I need to checkout **two repositories**. The pipeline has 3 jobs. The first one just checks if the license I need is present, then the second job starts to compile my code and the thrid job publishes it as a NuGet package.

When I try to run the pipeline, it seems to work fine until the publishing job, where it does not find the specification file. That happens because for the third job the variable **$(Build.SourcesDirectory)** points to **agent/_work/1/s**, while the code is checked out during the second job in **agent/_work/2/s**. For some reason, the second job creates a second working folder, when I try checking out more than one repository.

I have already tried using just one repository and it works fine (always uses **agent/_work/1/s**). As soon as I add a second repository to be checked out, it creates the second folder and messes with the **Build.SourcesDirectory** variable.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
pool:
  name: myPool
   
jobs:
- job: check_license
  displayName: Check license
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - powershell: |
      run something
    displayName: Check license
    
- job: compile_code
  displayName: Compile code
  dependsOn: check_license
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    path: ./s
    clean: true
  - checkout: git://myRepo
    path: ./s/myRepo
    clean: true
  - powershell: |
      run something
    displayName: Compiling code
      
- job: publish_code
  displayName: Publish code
  dependsOn: compile_code
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - powershell: |

      # Configuration file
      $nuspecFile = "\artifact_spec.nuspec"

      # Copy file to build folder
      Copy-Item "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$nuspecFile" -Destination $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
      
      ...
    displayName: Publish NuGet package
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround solution here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/checkout-step-creates-new-directory-in-work-every/1084115?viewtype=solutions

Basically the solution is to check out just one repository and clone the second repository with a git command in a script.